# Java Double Linked List Stack Tail error

Tags: java, linked-list, stack, push

I searched for this alot found alota similar answers but nothing to help my exact problem.

I'm doing a push method for my double linked list, while the pointers on the head work fine, the tail next and previous pointers do not work please help.

```
public class MyStack<E> implements MyDeque {

    private Node<E> head;
    private Node<E> tail;
    private int size;

    public MyStack() {
        head = null;
        tail = null;
        size = 0;
    }
    public void push(Object element) {
        Node<E> newNode = new Node(element);
       if(size == 0) {
           Node temp = new Node(head);
           head = newNode;
           head.next = head;
           head.previous = head;
           tail = head;
           tail.next = head;
           tail.previous = temp;          

          }
       else {     

           newNode.previous = head;
           head = newNode;
           newNode.next = tail;
           (tail.next).previous = tail;


       }//else statement
       size++;
    }//push()


    public Object peek() {
        if (size==0) return null;
        else
            return head;
    }


    public Object pop() {

      size--;
      if(size == 0) 
          return null;
      else {

         Node temp = new Node(head.previous);
         head = head.previous;
         head.next = tail;
         head.previous = temp;

         return head;

      }//else

    }//pop()

    @Override
    public int size() {

        return size;
    }


     private class Node<E> {
        private E data;
        private Node<E> next;
        private Node<E> previous;

        public Node(E data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
            this.previous = null;
        }
        public Node(E data, Node<E> next, Node<E> previous) {

            this.data = data;
            this.next = next;
            this.previous = previous;

        }//constructor

        public String toString() {
            return data+"";
        }

    }//class Node<E>
    public String toString() {

        return (head+" Head\n" + head.next  +" Head.Next\n" + head.previous+ " Head.previous\n"
                + tail+" Tail\n" + tail.next+" tail.next\n" + tail.previous+" tail.previous\n"); 

    }


}
```

Comment: A stack doesn't need a double linked list, you only need a pointer to the head and a next variable in Node. It looks like you have a wrap-around stack (head points to tail and vice versa), my question is - why? In my opinion, in `push` for `size == 0`, all 4 `next` and `previous` should be `null`, among other changes.

Answer (score 0):

The case where you push an object when the stack is empty does not look correct. The first node added should be assigned to head. Then the tail becomes the new node's head, this new node becomes the tail node's tail, and the new node itself becomes the tail.

Usually in a stack you add and remove elements at the end (the tail). The code doesn't make it very clear what you are trying to do with the *head* and *tail* members. Maybe it would be clearer for you if you name them *firstNode* and *lastNode*.

Answer (score 0):

I can actually see a few issues with this code

```
public class MyStack<E> implements MyDeque {

private Node<E> head;
private Node<E> tail;
private int size;

public MyStack() {
    head = null;
    tail = null;
    size = 0;
}
```

This looks fine

```
public void push(Object element) {
    Node<E> newNode = new Node(element);
   if(size == 0) {
       Node temp = new Node(head);
       head = newNode;
       head.next = head;
       head.previous = head;
       tail = head;
       tail.next = head;
       tail.previous = temp;          

      }
   else {     

       newNode.previous = head;
       head = newNode;
       newNode.next = tail;
       (tail.next).previous = tail;


   }//else statement
   size++;
}//push()
```

Bit confused why you are taking in an object instead of your generic E.

You really don't need the temp value here, in fact it looks like you are breaking your previous when you set `tail.previous = temp`

In your else you aren't setting the tail.previous correctly. The last line should be `tail.previous = head`. You also missed the head.next

So cleaned up a bit

```
public void push(E element) {
    Node newNode = new Node(E);
    if(size == 0) {
        head = newNode;
        head.next = head;
        head.previous = head;
        tail = head;
    } else {
        newNode.previous = head;
        head.next = newNode;
        newNode.next = tail;
        tail.previous = newNode;
        head = newNode;
    }
    size++;
}
```

In your pop method you probably want to move your size decrement after your size check, otherwise a 1 element stack will return null when popped.

edit: This would probably be easier with a singly linked list, or at least not a circular doubly linked list.

and adding at the end would probably be the more conventional way to do things.